# TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable in openpyxl function dataframe_to_rows

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl

I am using dataframe_to_rows function from openpyxl library.
I am trying to write the dataframe into an existing blank worksheet with formatting.
However, I am getting below error :
TypeError : 'float' object is not subscriptable

Below is the code for the same :

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.utils.dataframe import dataframe_to_rows

def copy_dataframe_to_file(file_path, df, sheet_name):

    wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_path)
    ws = wb[sheet_name]
    rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)    

    for r_idx, row in enumerate(rows, 1):
        for c_idx, value in enumerate(row, 1):
            ws.cell(row=r_idx, column=c_idx, value=value)

    ws.save(file_path)


Error Message Here: 

row = [data[j][idx] for j in range(ncols)] 
TypeError : 'float' object is not subscriptable
```

The line *row = [data[j][idx] for j in range(ncols)]* is from the library file *openpyx.utils.dataframe.py*.
I am unable to understand where the 'float' is coming from.

Comment: add full traceback

Comment: data[j] might be float, data[j][idx] is trying to access the idx th element of a float

Comment: What does `df.head()` look like?

Answer (score 0):

For testing purpose, I added a print statement in openpyx.utils.dataframe.py before the line *row = [data[j][idx] for j in range(ncols)]*  to get the values for data[j] and data[j][idx].

So data[j] is basically equivalent to column in a dataframe/table and its type is list (list of strings) and data[j][idx] is the value of first row in the column.
I was able to print the first column.
The trouble starts when the next column is a list of floats (actually list of integers but converted to list of floats) by dataframe_to_rows. That is where the above error is occuring.

I converted the entire dataframe to string type by below line before passing it to dataframe_to_rows.

```
df = df.to_string()
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)
```

With this, the error did not occur. However, this converts all blanks to 'nan' string and integers to float e.g. 102 to 102.0

To avoid this issue, I had to convert the entire dataframe to type 'object' before fetching rows with dataframe_to_rows with below line. This resolved the nan values and float representation of integers.

```
df = df.astype('object')
rows = dataframe_to_rows(df)
```